# R for Loop Add Value to New Column

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop in a R data frame to pull the Last Price of dataframe of stocks. I am having trouble appending the result to the original dataframe and using it as a second column. Here is the code I am working with thus far. I can get it to print but not add to a new column. I tried to set the loop value equal to a new column but I get an error

```
    for (i in df_financials$Ticker){
      df_financials$Last_Price=(bdp(i,'PX_LAST'))

     }


    Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Last_Price", value = list(PX_LAST = 
    NA_real_)) : 
    replacement has 1 row, data has 147 


Print(df_financials)

    Ticker
1     ENH Equity
2     AXS Equity
3     BOH Equity
4     CNA Equity
5     TRH Equity
```

Comment: Show a mock data.

Comment: You need `df_financials$Last_Price[i]=bdp(i, 'PX_Last')`.  As it stands, you're trying to replace the whole column with a single value.  But there are more intuitive commands out there that do the same thing, like `dplyr`'s `mutate` function as seen in Lyngbakr's comment below.  Note you'll need to install `plyr` before `dplyr`

Comment: If `bdp` is vectorized you could just use the `dplyr` package like this `df_financials %>% mutate(Last_Price = bdp(Ticker, 'PX_LAST'))`.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to specify the order to apply your command to the stated vector and when to stop [i.e., use `1:length(df$Var)` within `for()`]. Second, specify which row (i) of your new column to replace (i.e.,`df$var[i]`). Give the code below a try and see if that works.

```
for (i in 1:length(df_financials$Ticker)){
  df_financials$Last_Price[i]=(bdp(i,'PX_LAST'))
}
```

I'm not familiar with the bdp() function itself. However, I suspect the 
problem is that you are trying to pull data from a list with more stocks than you are interested in. If this is the case you need to reference the stock in row i that you want to obtain the last price for. If I'm understanding this correctly the code below should do the trick.

I'll assume that the list is something like

```
Stock<-data.frame(other_stocks = c("ENH","AXS","Rando1","BOH","CNA","TRH","Rando2","Rando3"), 
PX_LAST=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

Stock

```
for (i in 1:length(df$Ticker)){
    df$Last_Price[i]=(bdp(df$Ticker[i],'PX_LAST'))
}
```

Comment: Intuitively I know what you are saying. For some reason, that code does not register i as a string anymore and therefore can't pull 'PX-LAST'. If I run it i get "Expecting a string vector: [type=integer; required=STRSXP]." If I print i, it returns the index of each row